# Object Spilling in Ray

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ray

I have a script using ray like this:

```
import ray
from PIL import Image

ray.init(
    object_store_memory=1000 * 1024 * 1024 * 100,
    ignore_reinit_error=True,
    num_cpus=128,
    num_gpus=1,
)

img_paths = np.array([200k image paths])

@ray.remote
def read_img(path):

    img = np.asarray(Image.open(path))

    return img


images = ray.get([read_img.remote(path) for img_path in img_paths[:10000]])
```

When I process ~5000 images via `img_paths[:5000]`, this program executes in about 5 seconds. When I bump this up to ~10000, the program takes 4 minutes to execute and gives me messages like:

`(raylet) Spilled 132187 MiB, 12533 objects, write throughput 1052 MiB/s.`

This is my first time using ray, so I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Hi Gavin! For timely responses I recommend you link to this question in the [Ray Discuss site](https://discuss.ray.io/c/ray-core/8) or [Slack](https://www.ray.io/community). The Ray people monitor those closely and can answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this by [processing my images in batches](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/tasks/patterns/too-many-results.html). The system wasn't allocating the requested 100 GB of ram, so objects were still spilling. Looks something like this:

```
refs = [read_img.remote(path) for path in paths]
images = np.empty((1920, 1920))

for i in range(len(refs) // 5000 + 1):

    images = np.vstack(
        (images, np.array(ray.get(refs[i * 5000 : (i + 1) * 5000])))
    )
```